# jmrware linkify not accepting url without schema (http)

Tags: javascript, regex, string, url, linkify

I got a wierd issue with linkify'ing url to clickable links using javascript regular expression.

after digging a lot on so.com, i started using [jmrware/LinkifyURL.js](https://github.com/jmrware/LinkifyURL) to convert url's to clickable links. but when try to convert url without schema ((htt|ft)ps), it is not recognising the url at all.

example:

> http://www.google.com (accepting)
>   www.google.com(not accepting)
>   google.com(not accepting).

can anybody there help me to figure out solution for this.

Edit:
in my scenario i have to accept input from user in text area where user may enter any url. i have to linkify any url found in user input while showing on site.

here is my test content I'm trying to linkify.

```
> http://example.com:80                                            (linkified)<br/>
> http://example.com:80/path/                                      (linkified)<br/>
> http://example.com:80/path/file.txt                              (linkified)<br/>
> http://example.com:80/path/file.txt?query=val&var2=val2          (linkified)<br/>
> http://example.com:80/path/file.txt?query=val&var2=val2#fragment (linkified)<br/>
> http://example.com/(file's_name.txt)                             (linkified)<br/>
> http://[2001:0db8:85a3:08d3:1319:8a2e:0370:7348]                 (linkified)<br/>
> http://[2001:0db8:85a3:08d3:1319:8a2e:0370:7348]/file.txt        (linkified)<br/>
> http://youtube.com:80/path/file.txt?query=val&var2=val2          (linkified)<br/>
> www.example.me                                                   (not linkified)<br/>
> example.me                                                       (not linkified)<br/>
```

in above code last two strings are not linkified which i want to be. I tried negative lookbehind in JavaScript RegExp, even then no luck.

((?!(http|ftp|https|ftps)://)^[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)+([/?].*)?) - negative lookbehind

I'm newbie to so.com and please excuse me if I'm not clear in my question.

Comment: ((ht|f)ps) should be (http|ftp|https)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author of the [linkify project](https://github.com/jmrware/LinkifyURL) in question. By design, the `linkify()` function only matches URLs which have the scheme element. Without this restriction, there would be too many false positives. (Almost any string or substring is a valid URI.)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to ensure the `url` string is a link:

```
url = url.replace(/^(?!(?:http|https|ftp):\/\/)/i, 'http://');
```

Comment: I guess i am not clear in my question. please look into my question, I added an edit.